# What is a suitable step up transformer to allow me to use a Chinese appliance in the US?

Tags: power

I have been looking for a step up transformer to use a 140W appliance from China in the US. Ideally it wouldn't be one of the big bulky ones!

The closest thing I have found so far is [this transformer](http://a.co/iz8QEpy), but I would need an adapter at both ends (I think) to be able to plug it into a US outlet and to be able to plug my US appliance into it.

Does anyone know of a more suitable transformer, ideally that wouldn't require additional adapters?

Comment: What does "good" mean for you? Unfortunately this is a subjective term and therefore we can't really answer this.

Comment: By "Good" I mean one that doesn't require additional adapters to work mostly, but also will work OK for a 140 Watt appliance.

Comment: I have changed "Good" to "Suitable"

Comment: @BenHolness The StackExchange Q&A is best suited for questions that have a single, definitive answer; it doesn't work well for suggestions or reviews, which seem to be what you are asking for. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] and see if the question can be phrased so it doesn't ask for suggestions or lists.

Comment: Eg. What are the characteristics I should look for in an adapter to do  xxxx?

Comment: PS. Asking for product recommendations is grounds for closing in most or all SE sites, however they may be offered provided disclosure is given of any conflicts (to discourage spamming). In fact SE monetizes Amazon links by automatically converting them to affiliate links with SE as the beneficiary.

Comment: Beware that the device you linked is not a true transformer but rather an electronic voltage converter.  Much lighter and cheaper but the output is not as clean.  Some devices will not like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0022QOSDK?psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0022QOSDK) or similar is probably okay. 
[image]

I have a couple similar ones and a Chinese power bar. If you can find them locally you can save on shipping (a proper transformer will not be light!).

I appreciate your  desire to have something small and light, but keep in mind that virtually none of these devices are UL or CSA approved (CE means nothing) and I feel much safer with  something inside a GROUNDED METAL BOX, so even if it fails the worst you will likely get is some lungs full of toxic smoke, and not a fire or a fatal electric shock.

The shown receptacles accept both the parallel blade Chinese style and the angled variety, as well as the 2-pin Euro style. Not that securely, but they fit in.

I would also take the ratings with a bit of a grain of salt, and stay well below the maximum rating.